# How do smart contracts keep track of what eth address controls an NFT

Tags: tokens, nft, addresses

How does a NFT smart contract store which addresses have ownership over an NFT *or* do they ever store this information?

My goal is to query an NFT smart contract to get (for example) a merkle tree of addresses and then generate a zk proof that a certain address is in the merkle tree.

Answer (score 3):

From what I catch in your question, you would like to get the list of owners of an NFT contract. Trying to query this information manually is challenging and takes a lot of resources and time.

I suggest using a third-party API service, such as Moralis, to help you fetch the list of NFT owners to generate the zk-proof. It will be much cheaper, more efficient, and can be easily maintained in the future.

To fetch the list of NFT owners with Moralis, first install the NodeJS SDK:

```sh
npm install moralis @moralisweb3/common-evm-utils
```

then add this code here

```js
import Moralis  from 'moralis';
import { EvmChain } from '@moralisweb3/evm-utils';

try {
    const chain = EvmChain.ETHEREUM;

    const address = '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890';

    await Moralis.start({
        apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
        // ...and any other configuration
    });

    const response = await Moralis.EvmApi.nft.getNFTOwners({
        address,
        chain,
    });

    console.log(response?.result);
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

Then, you can simply change the parameters as you need. For parameter details, check out their API reference for this API [here](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/reference/get-contract-nfts). If you need a step-by-step tutorial for this API, they have it too right [here](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-nft-owners-by-an-address).

For this to work, you will also need a Moralis API Key, which you can get in https://admin.moralis.io

Hope this helps!

Comment: thx, will definitely try this out. some alternative methods I thought of were opensea api or google big query